# Height property working on ALL browser but Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with firefox and the height of the div that contains all the content. I can't figure out why the min-height:100% won't apply.

PS: If I use width:100% instead, it will work but will cause some troubles on pages where the height is more than the height of screen.

Website : [URL-Removed (Problem Solved)]

Screenshot :

Opera/Edge/Chrome :
[image: Working on Opera]

Firefox:
[image: Not Working on Firefox]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `min-height: 100%` try `min-height: 100vh`, `vh` is a new unit that refers to the view port height.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why SO requires you to supply the markup/code here and not as a link that's since been removed. This question is now worthless and will help no one (not that it would help anyone else anyway).

Comment: @Rob You're right. I was using the Inspinia Admin Bootstrap CSS in case someone wonder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set wrapper 100% height and it looks ok.
[image: Screen]

Comment: Thanks you ! The hints was to set height:100% on wrapper and not page-wrapper ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code :

```
height:auto;
```

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion but it hasn't worked. Makes no difference in FireFox

Answer (score 0):

In `#page-wrapper` you should use `height: 100%;` instead `min-height: 100%;`

Comment: As I said, this will cause troubles if the height of the page wrapper exceeds 100%